# Let $ S = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}, T = \{v_1, v_2,v_3\} $ be $2$ orthonormal bases of the subspace $W$. Which of the following is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, orthogonality

Let $ S = \{u_1, u_2, u_3\}, T = \{v_1, v_2,v_3\} $ be 2 orthonormal bases of the subspace $W$.

Let $ P = (p_1, p_2, p_3) $ where $ p_i = \begin{pmatrix} v_i \cdot u_1 \\ v_i \cdot u_2 \\ v_i \cdot u_3\\\end{pmatrix}$, for i = 1,2,3. Which of the following is true?

$ \quad $ (1) For any $ w \in W, P\begin{pmatrix} w \cdot u_1 \\ w \cdot u_2 \\ w \cdot u_3\\\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} w \cdot v_1 \\ w \cdot v_2 \\ w \cdot v_3\\\end{pmatrix}$

$ \quad $ (2)
For any $ w \in W, P\begin{pmatrix} w \cdot v_1 \\ w \cdot v_2 \\ w \cdot v_3\\\end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix} w \cdot u_1 \\ w \cdot u_2 \\ w \cdot u_3\\\end{pmatrix}$

$ \quad $ (3) 1, 2 are false

**(1) is true,** because P is the transition matrix from T to S, so P $\begin{pmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \\ u_3\\\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3\\\end{pmatrix}$ and (1) is just multiplying $ w $ on both sides, so they would still be equal? Is my reasoning correct? What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$ and $V = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$. Then $P = U^\top V$.

The equation in (1) can be rewritten as $P (U^\top w) = V^\top w$. The equation in (2) can be rewritten as $P(V^\top w) = U^\top w$.

(2) is true because $PV^\top w = U^\top VV^\top w = U^\top w$.

Comment: So, both (1) and (2) are true? I could also write $ P = V^T U $ right?

Comment: @user61239 No, $U^\top V \ne V^\top U$. The way $P$ is defined is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that $P$ is the transition matrix from $T$ to $S$.  That means it takes vectors written in terms of $V$ to the same vectors written in terms of $U$.  Thus $2)$ is true.